# creating folder on the site works only from inside the server

Tags: permissions, folder, assets

I am trying to create a folder on an asset library in SharePoint, while logging from outside the server, and it works fine. Using the same administrator account from inside the server, I was able to create the folder inside the library. How come? Is there any special configuration that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the culprit here is "alternate access mappings" in the central administration. make sure the AAM mappings for the web application/site collection is having correct url pointed in the correct zone with proper bindings.

if there is any problem with the AAM settings, then site collections behave in a very odd way especially for editing.